# Terraform how to define a variable to let user choose existing resource or create new one

Tags: azure, terraform

I am new to Terraform.
I am having this question, would like to ask here.

So I am creating a azurerm_storage_account with all these input variables

```
#ie: 

resource "azurerm_storage_account" "example" {
  name                     = "storageaccountname"
  resource_group_name      = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location                 = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  account_tier             = "Standard"
  account_replication_type = "GRS"

  tags = {
    environment = "staging"
  }
}
```

How to define a variable can allow user to choose the existing storage account or creating a new one.

I am thinking to do this:

```
variable "choice" {
  description = "Allow user to choose the existing storage account or creating a new one"
  type = string
  default = "create" 
}
```

Then I don't know where to use this variable to work with the azurerm_storage_account resource.

Any pointer would be appreciate!

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [count](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/meta-arguments/count.html) for that. Thus if your variable is "create", a new resource is going to be created. If its not, then a [azurerm_storage_account](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/data-sources/storage_account) data source will be used to query for details of the existing resource.

```
resource "azurerm_storage_account" "example" {

  count                    = var.choice == "create" ? 1 : 0

  name                     = "storageaccountname"
  resource_group_name      = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location                 = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  account_tier             = "Standard"
  account_replication_type = "GRS"

  tags = {
    environment = "staging"
  }
}

data "azurerm_storage_account" "example" {

 count                    = var.choice == "create" ? 0 : 1
 
 #...

}
```

Comment: Why do we need data block here to be able to use it?
Isn't data sources are read-only? 

Without data block I get an error says: 
"Because azurerm_storage_account.this has "count" set, its attributes must be
│ accessed on specific instances."

Comment: @XIAOLONGLI Because that's what you wrote that you want: "choose the existing storage account". There is no other way to refer to existing resources apart from data sources.

Comment: Thanks, this works!